# Facebook fanbox with custom CSS

Tags: php, facebook

I have a website running the following code:

```
<iframe class="fanbox" width="472" height="220" src="http://www.connect.facebook.com/widgets/fan.php?href=<?php echo urlencode('http://www.facebook.com/my-website-page'); ?>&amp;width=472&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=true&amp;stream=false&amp;header=false&amp;height=220&amp;css=<?php echo urlencode('http://mywebsite.com/css/fb-style.css'); ?>"></iframe>
```

It was working, but it's seems that facebook removed this method of getting the Fan Box. Now I receive a 404 Not Found Error: http://www.connect.facebook.com/widgets/fan.php

It was really removed/moved? How can I do this now?

Comment: i found some alternatives in google, but they all seems very different from each other. What is the "right way"?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Like Box [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/). If you just want the "Fans" images, then uncheck "stream", etc until you get what you desire. Then click "Get Code" and choose "IFrame" in the dialog box.

In your example, it would be:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=<?php echo urlencode('YOUR_FB_URL'); ?>&amp;width=292&amp;height=258&amp;show_faces=true&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;stream=false&amp;border_color&amp;header=false&amp" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:292px; height:258px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```